# YouTube MPEG-DASH segement's duration

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, youtube-analytics

Anyone knows what is YouTube's policy when generating MPEG DASH?

Especially what is the rule to decide the segment's duration?

For example, I found some files have ~ 4.8 sec per segment but some have ~4.4 sec. So it seems to not the same but depends on the unload videos.

Is it fixed? If not so, why it is not fixed for simplicity?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only YouTube can answer this.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the number of frames per second and the encoding structure? Different framerates would lead to different segment lengths, and you could for example always start the segment with an I-frame.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?